# How to uses stories in stories.js files from Storybook in a component.vue Vue js project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, storybook

Hello I just create my first Vue project using Vue CLI and added Storybook to it. I have by default the file `index.stories.js` in my `stories` folder. And I want to use the "withText" button in my component but I don't know how. This is what the default file looks like: (you can dm me if I'm not notified)

```
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions'
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links'

import MyButton from '../components/MyButton.vue'

export default {
  title: 'Button',
}

export const withText = () => ({
  components: { MyButton },
  template: '<my-button @click="action">Hello Button</my-button>',
  methods: { action: action('clicked') }
})

export const withJSX = () => ({
  render() {
    return <MyButton onClick={linkTo('Button', 'With Some Emoji')}>With JSX</MyButton>;
  }
})

export const withSomeEmoji = () => ({
  components: { MyButton },
  template: '<my-button>   </my-button>'
})
```

I tried asking in some discord servers, on youtube, but I found nothing. I'm new on Vue and I hope for an answer to help me see clearer please